# customized FilterAcceptsrow example

Tags: python, pyqt5

[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwJ7l.png)[Filtred Data[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlJRi.png)I'm new to Qt and i'm trying to come up with a simple approache to filter my data as it is shown in the example below, i have allready built the treeview table and the mainwindow but the Qsortproxyfiltermodel still seems intuitive to me, i'm expectating a combobox to send a single to the filter method after that the data should be updated automatically.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','A','A','B','C'],
            'Date':['2020-11-05','2020-11-06','2020-11-18','2020-12-01','2020-12-14','2020-11-15']})

df.groupby('Name').max()    ## The Filtering method should do somthing similliar to this.
```

I’m using a TableTreeView model which loads data from a csv file, i want to add
Filter which keeps only the latest dates corresponding for each unique value in the last name column. Thank you for helping me.

```py
import sys,csv

from PermissionsFilter import Ui_PermissionsFilter

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets ,QtGui

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMessageBox,QComboBox,QTableView,QCompleter,
QMainWindow,QPushButton, QCheckBox,QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QTextEdit,QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont,QPixmap,QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QDir,QDate,QTimer, QRegExp, QSortFilterProxyModel

import datetime
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QDate, QDateTime, QRegExp, QSortFilterProxyModel, Qt, QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool,
                          pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot,QTime)

import pandas as pd



MainDataBase=pd.read_csv(r'C:/MainDataBase.csv')
PermissionDataBase=pd.read_csv(r'C:/PermissionDataBase.csv')




class MySortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MySortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)


class PermissionWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_PermissionsFilter):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(PermissionWindow, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.setupUi(self)
         
        self.ViewBox.stateChanged.connect(self.close)

        self.proxyModel = MySortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)


        self.PermissionsFilterEdit.textChanged.connect(self.textFilterChanged)


        self.OriginalDataTree.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.OriginalDataTree.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.OriginalDataTree.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.OriginalDataTree.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.OriginalDataTree.sortByColumn(1, Qt.AscendingOrder)


        

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.OriginalDataTree.setColumnWidth(1,120)


    def textFilterChanged(self, text):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(search)
       
        
def addMail(model, Name,Matricule, Start, End,Day):
    model.insertRow(0)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 0), Name)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 1), Matricule)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 2), Start)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 3), End)
    model.setData(model.index(0, 4), Day)



def createMailModel(parent):
    model = QStandardItemModel(0, 5, parent)
    model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Last name")
    model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "key")
    model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Start")
    model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "End")
    model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Day")


    df1=MainDataBase.merge(PermissionDataBase,on='Matricule',how='outer').iloc[:,1]



    for i in PermissionDataBase.index:

        name=df1[i]
        mat=PermissionDataBase.iloc[i][0]
        s=PermissionDataBase.iloc[i][1]
        e=PermissionDataBase.iloc[i][2]
        d=QDateTime.currentDateTime()
#         d=str(DayBase.iloc[i][2])
        addMail(model,name,mat,s,e,d)

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=None
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PermissionWindow()
    window.setSourceModel(createMailModel(window))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you actually want to show? Also, are you using a treeview or a table? They are *not* the same thing, especially if your filtering needs to consider the hierarchy of the model.

Comment: the tabletree load data from csv file and display serval starting dates for each value in 'last name' column , what im trying to do is to add checkbox so only the last date for each last name is displayed, the result shall be same as it were return from the pandas groupby method that i added earlier.

Comment: Again, is it a table or a tree? Then, your request is still unclear, please try to find someone that can help you writing in English a *clear* explanation of what you want to achieve: what should be visible by default? Should those name and date entries be individual items in a table? Is there a hierarchy? Are those related by columns? There are so many aspects that are not explained in your question and comment, if you want help you must make them clear.